# How to set up Android Studio to build Facebook SDK?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I loaded the [SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk) via git. After that I imported it in Android Studio.

When I call `./gradlew clean facebook:assemble` I get a lot of 
`cannot find symbol` error messages.

Gradle can't find classes from the android-support lib and it can't find the R class too. But at the end the build finishes successful.

Are this error messages okay or do if have to fix something?

Android Studio shows this errors too. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the Facebook SDK via a gradle dependency.

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.2.0'
```

If you want to add the SDK as a module in Android Studio then the following should work:

Add the FacebookSDK to your project, at the same level as your 'app' directory.

Then you need to edit settings.grade and app/build.gradle

settings.grade

```
include ':FacebookSDK', ':app' // FacebookSDK needs to be first
```

app/build.gradle

```
compile project(':FacebookSDK')
```

Comment: Yes I know but this is not my problem. I want to change the Facebook SDK itself. But when I import it as a Android Studio project I get this errors :-(

Comment: I updated my answer, let me know if you still run into issues. That is how I added it before switching to gradle dependency in my project.

Comment: The problem was the lib folder in the sdk folder. There was another support-lib. After removing this the problem is gone

Answer (score 0):

The described problem was fixed with [this commit](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/commit/3434fc0cfa18ef887732ccc621d21349dccc5956).